# using sympy to convert ITE to piecewise

Tags: python, sympy, piecewise

How do I use sympy to convert `ITE` to a `piecewise`. `ITE` class has `_eval_rewrite_as_Piecewise(self, *args)`, but I am not able to figure out as to how do I use it.

I tried:

```
ITE(x,y,y)._eval_rewrite_as_Piecewise(x,y)
```

but it actually raised error. So how do I use it and what arguments should be passed as `*args`, or am I doing the wrong way?

Answer (score 0):

Since the answer doesn't depend on the condition, the sample you gave rides to y and there is no rewriting possible. But try `ITE(x,y,z).rewite(Piecewise)` to see it in action.